# Google Cloud unable to receive logs from the subscription when the encryption selected as customer managed

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Google Cloud unable to receive logs from the subscription when the encryption selected as customer-managed

Comment: Can you tell what products are you using ? Please provide more details in general - what is your goal, set-up etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced what you're trying to do and below are the steps I took. Right now my subsription gets messages published by pub-sup topic with a customer managed encryption key.

Here are the steps:

1. I've [created a Key ring and a key](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/creating-keys) at [Security > Cryptographic keys](https://console.cloud.google.com/security/kms)
2. Then created new pub-sub topic and selected my key. You have to grant your service account rights to use that key. When you select it you will be presented with a window with a button `GRANT`;
   [image]
3. After clicking `GRANT` ([you can do this earlier like this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/using-customer-managed-keys#service-account-access)) then clicked `Create Topic`
4. Then created subscription named "sub1` and selected topic "pub1".
5. I've swithced to topics again and selected the one I created
6. I've [published some test messages](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#publishing_messages)
   7  Went back to subscriptions and selected mine, then clicked on "view messages" and got a list of all messages I've sent.
   [image]

You may also find this documentation on [configuring message encryption](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/encryption) and [using customer managed keys](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/using-customer-managed-keys) usefull.